# ffmpeg, Invalid PCM packet

Tags: shell, ffmpeg

I'm attempting to slow down audio with ffmpeg.  I'm doing it in 8 stages like so:

```
ffmpeg -i output5.aiff -filter:a "atempo=0.5" -vn output6.aiff
```

but when I get to the sixth stage I get this error:

```
Multiple frames in a packet.ed= 324x[pcm_s16be @ 0x7f81e880c600] Invalid PCM packet, data has size 3 but at least a size of 4 was expectedError while decoding stream #0:0: Invalid data found when processing input
```

and the audio gets cut short.  Any idea what's going wrong?

Comment: If no answer here, try the FFMPEG support forum and let us know the answer. :-) http://ffmpeg.gusari.org/

Comment: Didn't know there was a forum, thanks, have posted there as well.

Comment: Have you tried doing it in one pass?

Comment: Yes I have.  Originally I tried video and audio streams together like so `ffmpeg -i test.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:v]setpts=305.04672897196261*PTS, scale=320:240, fps[v];[0:a]atempo=0.5, atempo=0.5, atempo=0.5, atempo=0.5, atempo=0.5, atempo=0.5, atempo=0.5, atempo=0.5, atempo=0.807668329177057[a]" -map "[v]" -map "[a]" output5.mp4`.  It looks like the problem is occurring at about the same time in the audio, about 7 hours in.

Comment: Is the audio of use, or is it a token stream?

Comment: No I need both streams extended.

Comment: I suspect that 34 hours of audio contains a greater number of audio samples than can be indicated in the metadata of MP4 or similar formats. Try your process with `-ar 8000` added - for testing purposes. If it works, increase till it doesn't.

Comment: 8000 didn't work so I tried 1000.  Same error but it says `Multiple frames in a packet.ed= 317x`